# Pandas: How to create date32 dtype datetime objects?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with parquet and I need to use `date32[day]` objects for my dates but I am unclear how to use pandas to generate this exact datatype, rather than a timestamp.

Consider this example:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date.today()]})
df1.to_parquet('testdates.parquet')
pq.read_table("testdates.parquet")  # date32[day]
```

```
# pandas version

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2022-04-07')]})
df2.to_parquet('testdates2.parquet')
pq.read_table("testdates2.parquet")  # timestamp[us]
```

Comment: In the second code block, second line, can you try `df2.to_parquet('testdates2.parquet').astype(dat32[day])`? Basically specifying the datatype when converting dataframe to parquet [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: That does not work, unfortunately: `TypeError: data type 'date32[day]' not understood`; `df2['date'].astype('date32[day]')`

Comment: Ok. So can you first convert datetime to this datatype (in first line)  before going to second line and writing to parquet?

Comment: I also cannot -- pandas interprets the datetime object as an object datatype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `pandas` integraton with `pyarrow` [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html)

```
import pyarrow as pa
from datetime import date

df2 = pd.Series({'date':[date(2022,4,7)]})
df2_dat32 = pa.array(df2)

print("dataframe:", df2)
print("value of dataframe:", df2_dat32[0])
print("datatype:", df2_dat32.type)
```

Output

```
dataframe: date    [2022-04-07]
dtype: object
value of dataframe: [datetime.date(2022, 4, 7)]
datatype: list<item: date32[day]>
```

**Edit**: If you have entire column of dates, you will need to first convert datetime to date and then use same method as above. See example below:

```
import pyarrow as pa
from datetime import date

#create pandas DataFrame with one column with five
#datetime values through a dictionary
datetime_df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['2021-01-15 20:02:11',
                                '1989-05-24 20:34:11',
                                '2020-01-18 14:43:24',
                                '2021-01-15 20:02:10',
                                '1999-04-04 20:34:11']})

datetime_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime_df['DateTime']).dt.date

date_series = pd.Series(datetime_df['Date']) 
print(date_series)
```

Output:

```
0    2021-01-15
1    1989-05-24
2    2020-01-18
3    2021-01-15
4    1999-04-04
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Then use pyarrow for conversion:

```
df2_dat32 = pa.array(date_series)

print("datatype of values in the dataframe with dates:", type(date_series[0]))
print("value of dataframe after converting using pyarrow:", df2_dat32[0])
print("datatype after converting using pyarrow :", df2_dat32.type)
```

Output:

```
datatype of values in the dataframe with dates: <class 'datetime.date'>
value of dataframe after converting using pyarrow: 2021-01-15
datatype after converting using pyarrow : date32[day]
```

Comment: Thank you -- but how would I convert an entire column of dates to date32?

Comment: Do you need dates in a specific format or yyyy-mm-dd is okay?

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd is great, as its for the `date` type column in sql

Comment: Updated my answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas 2.0 [allows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/pyarrow.html) to specify PyArrow types by adding `[pyarrow]` suffix.

Let's use your initially provided example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [pd.to_datetime('2022-04-07')]})
df2.dtypes
```

```
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

We can simply convert `datetime64[ns]` into `day32[day]` using [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method:

```py
df2 = df2.astype({'date': 'date32[pyarrow]'})
df2.dtypes
```

```
date    date32[day][pyarrow]
dtype: object
```

We see that the Pandas uses the expected `date32` type. Furthermore, saving the file in parquet format, and the type will persist:

```py
df2.to_parquet('testdates2.parquet')
pq.read_table("testdates2.parquet")
```

```
pyarrow.Table
date: date32[day]
----
date: [[2022-04-07]]
```

Note that Pandas does not yet have the [equivalent Pandas-extensions type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/arrays.html#pyarrow) to the pyarrow-backend `date32` type.