# Unable to write parquet with DATE as logical type for a column from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, parquet, fastparquet

I am trying to write a parquet file which contains one date column having logical type in parquet as DATE and physical type as INT32. I am writing the parquet file using pandas and using fastparquet as the engine since I need to stream the data from database and append to the same parquet file. Here is my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

sql = "SELECT TO_VARCHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') AS "REPORT_DATE" FROM DUMMY;"

def create_stream_enabled_connection(username, password, host, port):
   conn_str = f"mydb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}"
   engine = create_engine(conn_str, connect_args={'encrypt': 'True', 'sslValidateCertificate':'False'})
   connection = engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True)
   return connection

connection = create_stream_enabled_connection(username, password, host, port)

ROWS_IN_CHUNK = 500000
# Stream chunks from database
for dataframe_chunk in pd.read_sql(text(sql), connection, chunksize=ROWS_IN_CHUNK):
   if os.stat(local_path).st_size == 0:  # If file is empty
      # write parquet file
      dataframe_chunk.to_parquet(local_path, index=False, engine='fastparquet')
   else:
      # write parquet file
      dataframe_chunk.to_parquet(local_path, index=False, engine='fastparquet', append=True)
```

**Problem:**

I am unable to get the logical type to be DATE and physical type to be INT32 in the output parquet from pandas `to_parquet` function using `fastparquet` as engine.

**A few things that I have tried:**

- If I take the REPORT_DATE coming from database as string and put it to parquet, then the logical type is STRING. Doesn't work for me.
- If I take the REPORT_DATE coming from database as string and convert it to datetime using the following code, then the dtype is `datetime64[ns]` and logical type in parquet is `Timestamp(isAdjustedToUTC=false, timeUnit=nanoseconds, is_from_converted_type=false, force_set_converted_type=false)` and physical type is `INT64`. Doesn't work for me.

`dataframe_chunk['report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe_chunk['report_date'], format='%Y%m%d')`

I need the parquet logical type to be `DATE` and physical type to be `INT32` since this parquet will be loaded directly to bigquery and the REPORT_DATE column will go to a `DATE` type column in bigquery. See the bigquery documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#type_conversions

If I try to store STRING or DATETIME column in parquet and load it in bigquery, bigquery fails by saying that it expected the column with another type.

Comment: Posted the question on fastparquet github
https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/880

Comment: Based on the answer from mdurant, i changed my code to use pyspark to write the parquet file with DATE was logicial type.

Comment: Could you clarify why the datetime approach doesn't work for you?  If your schema in BQ is predefined as datetime BQ should interpret the value correctly.

Comment: I guess this is because the column is in nanos and bq only supports microsends or milliseconds today.  I need to check if we have an open feature request to support nanoseconds otherwise we can add one

Comment: In BQ, my type is date, not datetime. If I would have had datetime in BQ, then there was no problem since fastparquet was also outputting datetime. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/issues/880#issuecomment-1697436417

The short story is: fastparquet cannot do this right now. I don't know how you can persuade bigquery to accept the current style of output, but I would think there must be a way, since the 64-bit format is valid parquet.

Comment: Just to clarify the date logical type  is only specified for [int32](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#date). For backwards compatibility reasons BQ will not auto infer a datetime column from a parquet column, however when loading data into a preexisting table that has a datetime column the correct conversion will happen)

Comment: Noted above but BQ doesn't support nanosecond precision yet.

Answer (score 1):

Pyarrow doesn't support appending to a file  but converting the column to a [date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787782/pandas-how-to-create-date32-dtype-datetime-objects) and using the pyarrow engine I believe will write out columns with the correct logical  type.

Depending on your exact need for streaming/appending you might be able to keep the the file open and append row batches until you are ready to upload.  Or you can write out a series of files into an object store and load them into BQ in a single load job.

Comment: Yes, you are right but i used fastparquet in the first place to have append option since I needed 1 file (this is due to my usecase). I used pyspark to write the file and load to BQ ultimately.